# Unknown error After updating chromedriver 2.29 needed for chrome 57

Tags: webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the error below image:
 Updated chrome driver to latest i.e 2.29 for my chrome version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMtNi.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like a browser/driver version incompatibility.  What do you get with `webdriver-manager status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you've *installed* chromedriver v2.29, from your stack trace states it's running v2.26. This seems to be a bug with `webdriver-manager`, where it does not use the latest version. Try cleaning out your `webdriver-manager` folder, and re-updating so you only have the latest...

`node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager clean`

`node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update`

Or if you have Protractor installed globally:

`webdriver-manager clean`

`webdriver-manager update`

If that doesn't work, it's likely a chromedriver bug... [perhaps #1751](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1751&q=cannot%20get%20automation%20extension&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: i have already tried this before .its shows same error , and the interesting thing is after clean webdriver-manager, when i run test still i can see in error   (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 
,its really strange

Comment: The error shows Protractor is still using 2.26. I updated my answer to ensure you're clearing out the `node_modules` folder as well.

Comment: might be, i did uninstall node and reinstall everything, again , thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

try execute the following command

webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.29

webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=2.29

Hope it would resolve

Your chrome ver 57 and driver ver 26 which is incompatible version, I too had a same issue but above work around helped me